# setting position of text - top:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to set the position of a text dynamically based on screen height.

```css
#txt{
       position: absolute;
       top: 685px;
    }

    html,body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }


    #pic
    {
       width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <image src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/4/47/Horiz-line.JPG/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/600?cb=20050929041542" id="pic"></image>

    <div id="txt">
    Hello world
    </div>
```

The goal is to the make text `hello world` above the horizontal line on all browser sizes. 
My attempt works on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxoGYy) on fullscreen windows but fails when you run it here.

Comment: why repeating the same question ? edit the previous one to add more clarification

Comment: @hasnt been solved

Comment: we don't simply repeat a question because it's not solved ... improve it by adding more detail, wait ... and if still nothing consder adding a bounty ... by the way it was not solved because you wasn't clear enough with your needs

Comment: @TemaniAfif got it thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Why not show the text *before* the image? And if you need it closer to the line, assuming the line is at the center of 600x600px image, then you can position it relative from top by half of the image:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#txt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;                      /* position of text set to half */
  transform: translateY(-100%);  /* just moving the text div a bit back */
}

#pic {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="txt">Hello world</div>
  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/uncyclopedia/images/4/47/Horiz-line.JPG/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/600?cb=20050929041542" id="pic">
</div>
```

EDIT: `img` is wrapped with `div`. Position of text can be set up using percentage of image height.

Comment: that works if the position you want is half of the image. But, I am looking for more general position like what if i want to place it quarter of the image

Comment: and also that doesn't support if the browser size is diffrent

Comment: @halmos Better now?